What causes the Mikheyev-Smirnov-Wolfenstein (MSW) Effect? Virtual Z bosons?
What causes the neutrinos to oscillate more often or rapidly? Are they being “bounced around” by Z bosons in the intense furnace of the Sun?  Is it due to an intense weak current?

just for reference; Wikipedia: Mikheyev-Smirnov-Wolfenstein effect and A. Y. Smirnov's arXiv: The Mikheyev-Smirnov-Wolfenstein (MSW) Effect
